# Не подсвечивать почту

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, javascript, match, replace

есть код который находит текстовые ссылки и делает их гипер ссылками, но он также делает гипер сылками и почту, а этого делать не нужно. Как это исправить.
вот код:

```
$(".paragraph").each(function(index, elem){
    var mess = $(this).html();      
    var reg = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}):\/\/)*?([-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@{1})?(([-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,3})(:\d+)?((\/[-\+~%\/\.\w]+)?\/?([&?][-\+=&;%@\.\w]+)?(#[\w]+)?)?)/igm;

    mess = mess.replace(reg, function(s){
        var str = (/:\/\//.exec(s) === null ? "http://" + s : s );
        return "<a target='_blank' href=\""+ str + "\">" + str  + "</a>"; 
    });    
    $(elem).html(mess);
});
```

Comment: @MaXiM3006, вот так:  

    var reg = /(((ftp|https?):\/\/)[\-\w@:%_\+.~#?,&\/\/=]+)/igm;

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, ссылок с `@` у вас не будет

```
var reg = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}):\/\/)*?([-;:&=\+\$,\w]+)?(([-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,3})(:\d+)?((\/[-\+~%\/\.\w]+)?\/?([&?][-\+=&;%@\.\w]+)?(#[\w]+)?)?)/igm;
```

Comment: Распарсить этот ад я не могу, но вижу что ещё одна собака там есть.

Вообще контент надо на серверной стороне править. JS нужен что-бы поведение задавать, а не структуру.

Answer (score 0):

Удали из своей регулярки правила с собакой "@" : http://take.ms/xF6ft

Comment: это приведет к удалению ссылок во всем элементе.
правильный ответ:
 var reg = /(((ftp|https?):\/\/)[\-\w@:%_\+.~#?,&\/\/=]+)/g;